# Is the automorphism group of a homogeneous (locally finite) tree unimodular?

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, graph-theory, trees

I have seen somewhere (that I don't remember now) that the (full) automorphism group of a k-regular tree is unimodular. I assume a k-regular tree is the same thing as the homogeneous tree of degree k (Is it true?). So my questions are

1. Is the above statement true? Where can I find a proof?
2. Are there other situations in which the automorphism groups of graphs are unimodular locally compact totally disconnected groups?
3. How is the unimodularity of the automorphism group of a tree (graph)  related to the geometric structure of the tree (graph)?

Thank you for your help, in advance!

Comment: Yes it's unimodular. One proof is that it has cocompact lattices, and a locally compact group with a lattice is always unimodular.

Comment: For 3 it's a bit delicate. I guess you assume implicitly that the graph is connected, has finite valency, and has a cocompact group of isometries. There exists cocompact trees with non-unimodular automorphism groups, so unimodularity is not a QI-invariant.

Comment: @YvesCornulier: Thank you again for your comments. I was wondering what reading materials do you recommend to learn more about analytical aspects of automorphism groups of trees? I am reading the book "Harmonic analysis and representation theory  for groups acting on homogeneous trees" by Figa-Talamanca and Nebbia now.

Comment: For regular and biregular trees, the automorphism group satisfies the Howe-Moore property, see Alexander Lubotzky, Shahar Mozes. Asymptotic properties of unitary representations of tree automorphisms. In: "Harmonic Analysis and Discrete Potential Theory"
(Frascati 1991). Plenum Press, 1992.

Comment: The Mass Transport Principle is, for homogeneous graphs, equivalent to the unimodularity of the automorphism group. It is useful to study random processes on the considered graph. References are "Group-invariant percolation on graphs" and "Probability on trees and networks". For a study of the autmorphism group of the rooted binary tree, see chapter 8 of "Topics in Geometric group theory" (de la Harpe).